# Is there a way to apply css for child only and not grandchild?

Tags: html, css

I want to provide a padding of 30px to p element inside the div element. But I don't want that padding to be applied to the img tag inside p.

```html
<div class="desc">
  <p>first paragraph</p>
  <p><img src="....."></p>
  <p>second paragraph</p>
</div>
```

I have attached the required result below.

[image]

Comment: note 1: img shouldn't be wrapped in a p tag. The image will have a padding of 30 because the parent (p) tag has the padding. just set img to have 0 padding

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `>` selector.

`div > p { padding: 30px; }`

It applies the styling only on the **direct** child elements (= direct descendants)

Answer (score 0):

As #Khaaytil stated, you can use > between selectors.
Look here for more reference [> direct descendant selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp)

For different scenarios u can see these 2 also:

Using [+ adjacent sibling selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)

Using [~ non-adjacent sibling selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp)

Also you can try [:only-child Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_only-child.asp)

**But** as best practice you should really not wrapping images in a

tag. Just put the image between the 2 tags, or wrap it in another tag.