# Select only level being hovered, but not its parents or children

Tags: html, css, selector

*(I'm aware there's a myriad of CSS selector questions already, yet I couldn't find an answer to this one, unfortunately; so please bear with me.)*

I have HTML with the following properties:

- Some nodes are to be always visible. They can be nested.
- Each of these nodes always has exactly one "info child node" which is to be shown only while its parent node is hovered. (There can possibly be other non-info child nodes, since those can be nested).
- I want **only the info for the currently hovered node to be shown exclusively**.

Example (here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/philippkoch/tg8yke3m/2)):

```css
.always-visible {
  display: block;
}

.info-on-parent-hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
  display: none;
}

.always-visible {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #777;
}

.always-visible:hover {
  background-color: #3377cc;
}

.always-visible:hover>.info-on-parent-hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="always-visible">
  node A [top-level node]
  <div class="info-on-parent-hover">some info about A</div>
</div>

<div class="always-visible">
  node B [top-level node]
  <div class="info-on-parent-hover">some info about B</div>

  <div class="always-visible">
    node C [child node of B]
    <div class="info-on-parent-hover">some info about C</div>
  </div>

  <div class="always-visible">
    node D [child node of B]
    <div class="info-on-parent-hover">some info about D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works so far, more or less, but my goal is that only one 'info node' is shown at a time (i.e. the one belonging to its parent). So:

How can I **select only the `div class=".info-on-parent-hover"` whose parent is currently hovered** (and not those of its ancestors, siblings or descendants; i.e. when node D is hovered, node B's info must not also be shown)?

Comment: Use the [child combinator (`>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to apply css for child only and not grandchild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54693730/is-there-a-way-to-apply-css-for-child-only-and-not-grandchild)

Comment: I do use the child combinator already (see `.always-visible:hover > .info-on-parent-hover`) - but in a wrong way, it seems.

Comment: Hovering an element always means hovering its parent as well. When you hover `D`, then `B` is also in the `:hover` state, that is simply how it is. Same goes for anything "above" `B` - including `body` and `html`. (Also, this is based on DOM structure, not how it displays.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a basic mistake: Your hovered parent contains a grandchild; simply make a sibling hover condition and it will work
[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/8eto43ja/)

```css
.always-visible {
    display: block;
}
.info-on-parent-hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
  display: none;
}
.always-visible {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #777;
}
.always-visible .text-to-hover:hover {
  background-color: #3377cc;
}
.always-visible .text-to-hover:hover + .info-on-parent-hover {
    display: block;    
}
```

```html
<div class="always-visible">
  <div class="text-to-hover">
  node A [top-level node]</div>
  <div class="info-on-parent-hover">some info about A</div>
</div>

<div class="always-visible">
  <div class="text-to-hover">
  node B [top-level node]
  </div>
  <div class="info-on-parent-hover">some info about B</div>
  
  <div class="always-visible">
  <div class="text-to-hover">
    node C [child node of B]
    </div>
    <div class="info-on-parent-hover">some info about C</div>
  </div>

  <div class="always-visible">
  <div class="text-to-hover">
  node D [child node of B]</div>
    <div class="info-on-parent-hover">some info about D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use the "Copy snippet to answer" button to copy the code (which works on *this* site) to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS selector:

```css
.info-on-parent-hover:has(~ .always-visible:hover) {
  display: none;
}
```

This selector works effectively to hide the `.info-on-parent-hover` elements when their sibling `.always-visible` elements are being hovered. However, it's important to note that the `:has()` pseudo-class is not supported in [all browsers](https://caniuse.com/css-has), so its usage may be limited. In browsers that do not support it, you may need to use JavaScript based solution.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! It's important to me to not exclude Firefox users (or any at all, for that matter, if possible), so that's not an option here, but it's a good to know about the possibility.